# Setting Formik errors in onSubmit (Check validity of credentials in onSubmit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, formik

At the minute, I am trying to use Formik to check if a date has been taken on a calendar. Problem is, I do not know how to throw a formik error in the onSubmit function. Basically, it is like checking the validity of a login on the onSubmit, but I just dont know how to do it. Right now, I have

````
onSubmit={(data, {setSubmitting, resetForm}) => {
                let email = `${data.counselor}@gmail.com`;
                getCalendar(email).then(calData => {
                    if(calData.data.data) {
                        calData.data.data.items.forEach(date => {
                     //Start time is defined.
                            if(startTime) {
                              //I do not know how to throw formik error here.
                                errors.date = "Start Date and Time Taken! Find Another Time, Day, or Duration!"```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setErrors` to update errors

```
onSubmit={(data, {setSubmitting, resetForm, setErrors}) => {
  ...
  setErrors({date: "Start Date and Time Taken! Find Another Time, Day, or Duration!"})
  ...
```

Comment: Update: I did some testing and the function works. the issue is when executing it in the forEach. I don't know if it is because of the async of it or what, but when it is outside of the loop, it is usable.